# Display Current Date using shortcode

Tags: date

I am using the below code to display current date in php using shortcodes for Indian time zones:

```php
add_shortcode( 'current_date', 'mth_footer_date2' );
function mth_footer_date2() {
    ob_start();
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    echo gmdate("jS F Y");
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

We need to add `[current_date]` Shortcode to display current date. This code is displaying date but I think, this is not in Indian Timezone. Please provide me such codes to display time in Indian Timezone. I want Date in following format, **Sunday, 24th October, 2021**.

Also provide ways to show tomorrow date in same format.

Comment: Instead of using the `ob_start()` / `echo` / `ob_get_clean()`, you can simply `return date( "jS F Y" );`. Note that, per [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/), shortcode callbacks should never output content directly, but should always `return` the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`date()`](https://php.net/date) in place of [`gmdate()`](https://php.net/gmdate), which returns the date/time for GMT.

To get the output you want, change the code to:

```
echo date('l, jS F, Y');
```

For displaying tomorrow's date, use the following code accordingly:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('tomorrow');
echo date('l, jS F, Y', $timestamp);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but I have another question, when i put this shortcode in Title, date, shows perfectly. But, when I share my wordpress, In preview, only [current_date] shortcode is shown. I don't get date. how can I fix this issue?

Comment: As @Pat J pointed out, you should return the content and not output it directly. Did you change your code to do this and still see `[current_date]` instead of the expected text?